# what is the meaning of ‘color’ when creating image with PIL.Image.new()?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

the pillow doc says the image will be a single channel pic when the `color` given a single integer, however I tried several times and don’t know why the image is not grey as a single channel image will be. Here is the code:

```py
from PIL import Image
im = Image.new(‘RGB’, [100, 100], 100) # this pic is deep red
im1 = Image.new(‘RGB’, [100, 100], 1000) # this pic is red
im2 = Image.new(‘RGB’, [100, 100], 10000) # this pic is black
```

So, how the integer is interpreted by PIL? Is this converted using a color palette?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In doc [Image.new](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.new) I see something different.

When you use `RGB` then it creates 3 channels and you should use tuple (R,G,B) as `color` to set values in all channnels for all pixels. If you use single integer/float then it may convert it to tuple (R,G,B).

If you use `L` then it creates 1 channel and then you should use single integer/float to set color for all pixels

But `color` doesn't change number of channels.

---

**EDIT:** converting 3x8bit `R,G,B` to/from 24bit value

```
value = 1000
R = value%256
value = value//256
G = value%256
value = value//256
B = value%256

print(R,G,B)
print(R+(G*256)+(B*256*256))
```

Result

```
232 3 0
1000
```

Comment: when using `RGB`, how integer is converted to tuple?

Comment: `R,G,B` is tuple 3 x 8bit which you can represent as 24bit value `R+(G*256)+(B*256*256)`